# Read receipt from someone who wasn't sent the email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm using Outlook with Microsoft Exchange - an email was sent to several external addresses, and a read receipt was received back - but from someone who the mail wasn't sent to.

I'm not sure how this has happened - if one of the recipients has a redirect or a rule to redirect on their mail to another address, could this be the reason?

Comment: many thanks for all your answers - i thought it would be something like a redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Richard's response, if a recipient has a delegate set up to automatically receive all email that was sent to that recipient, it would happen, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to resend an email manually in Outlook 2003 (Open the message > Actions > Resend This Message...) and if a read receipt was requested then the person the message was resent to can send a receipt (and it will be sent from their account).

So, yes, that could be the reason.

Comment: Resending a received message, like it was coming from the original sender? (Of course, anyone could fake the Sender, but the email client making faking a Sender too easy doesn't make much sense...)

Comment: Yes, like it was sent from the original sender, but no faking is involved. The orignal To: and From: headers remain the same and Resent-To: and Resent-From: headers are added.

Comment: Then I wouldn't be surprised if only Outlook would show something like "Resent by" (like it also shows that "on behalf of" when it encounters a "Sender" header), while many other clients would ignore the extra headers... Is re-sending it (like that) ever useful?

Answer (score 0):

Even without a delegate getting forwarded messages, anyone with permissions to the real recipients's mailbox would be able to read it with their credentials and the read receipt would show them as the reader, not the recipient (who may or may not have read it at that point).